# How to create a python function for a column that can divide the values to classes

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have a column 'payment_value'. I want to create another column and classify as High, Mid and low from the payment_value column .

Below is the sample input

```
payment_value
0   146.87
1   204.27
2   333.52
3   336.17
4   401.92
```

Below is the function I've created.

```
def classes(datacolumn):
    sorted(datacolumn)
    Q1,Q2 = np.percentile(datacolumn, [25,75])
    if Q1 < datacolumn:
        print('Low')
    elif Q2 >= datacolumn and Q2 < datacolumn:
        print('Med')
    else:
        print('High')
```

When i apply the function to below dataframe i get error.

```
data3['bins'] = classes(data3[['payment_value']])
```

Error:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: It is not clear which line is causing the problem or how you run the code.
Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First `sorted(datacolumn)` doesn't do what
you expect when `datacolumn` is a dataframe, use this instead:

```
datacolumn.sort_values(by='payment_value')
```

Second, `Q1 < datacolumn` is a so-called *vectorized* operation, it compares Q1
to *each* element of datacolumn, and returns a DataFrame object, with the
boolean results. It does not return a boolean value, which is why you get the
*"The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous"* error. You would need to
iterate over your data, or use `apply`as suggested by @Michael Sidorov.

Finally, your classes function only does `print`s, it doesn't return
anything. You need to make it return something if you want to assign a result
to data3['bins']

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Pandas.apply` instead. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def classes(val, Q1, Q2):
    payment_value = 'None'
    if val < Q1:
        payment_value = 'Low'
    elif Q1 < val <= Q2:
        payment_value = 'Med'
    else:
        payment_value = 'High'
    return payment_value


if __name__=='__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(payment_value=[146.87, 204.27, 333.52, 336.17, 401.92]))
    Q1,Q2 = np.percentile(df.payment_value.values, [25,75])
    df.loc[:, 'bins'] = df.loc[:, 'payment_value'].apply(classes, Q1=Q1, Q2=Q2)
    print(df)
```

Cheers.